# Need salesforce syllabus with topic

Tags: training

I need salesforce syllabus with topic. I want to learn salesforce online can anyone out here provide me with salesforce syllabus which contains all the topics in salesforce. I want to learn online so please also suggest some best materials where i can start from basic.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of thing to learn in salesforce.com so prepare one by one .
first i will advice go through this http://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/
http://salesforceeasy.blogspot.in/
after that you go with  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs?filter_text=&service=Force.com&select_type=&version=32.0&lang=en-us&sort=title search in Library Documentations you get everything 
in this. and check this [Where To start Learning With Salesforce Development](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17126/where-to-start-learning-with-salesforce-development)
 Thanx