# Beginner: how to start

Tags: learning

I am a beginner in Salesforce. Do you have some informations to learn as much as possible in a short time?

Edoardo

Comment: This is too opinion based for SFSE, however there is a good learning question that we've kept around for these scenarios :) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17126/where-to-start-learning-with-salesforce-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the instruction contained in this link.:
https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/
Start with the Admin section. If you know programming also the third part is extremely interesting.

Andrea

Comment: Trialhead is your guide for anything to learn .Get all badges as well as you learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading "Salesforce essentials for Administrators". I have read this and its very well explained with screen shots and step by step implementations.