# Salesforce beginner: How to start

Tags: developer

I am Brazilian, I would like some guidance on how to start a salesforce developer career. I am sorry for my english. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This site generally works best when you have a specfic and narrow problem you're stuck on, and can share what you've tried so far with us. The stackexchange network isn't meant to handle long discussions. Probably the best resource for people new to Salesforce (or just new to a part or concept that Salesforce uses) is https://trailhead.salesforce.com

Comment: Hey folks, we already have a nice [community wiki](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17126/where-to-start-learning-with-salesforce-development) question about getting started on Salesforce. Particularly since this topic is very broad, it would be wonderful if y'all could work towards improving or updating the community wikis there. I'm going to close this post out as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) and follow any of the trails that interest you (e.g. a Salesforce User, Administrator, Developer, etc). All of this for free, and you can get a free [Developer Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup?d=70130000000td6N) that you can use for development, building reports, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great article from Salesforce Ben that talks about becoming an SF Developer: https://www.salesforceben.com/8-steps-to-become-a-salesforce-developer/

It's a little light on info, but for a beginner who just wants to know how to become a dev, this is a good intro.

The main thing you want to focus on is being a good admin and understanding basic and advanced admin functions before moving into developing applications. Some may disagree with this, if they have prior programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Sfdc99](https://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/) great for absolute beginner to learn about programming in Salesforce.

To get started, you need a [developer org](https://developer.salesforce.com) to do your development.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the topics I could find from the trailhead. You could go from simple topics like soql/sosl from the trailhead and then move up the difficulty level so that it would be easy to understand.

- Salesforce Platform
- SOQL / SOSL
- VisualForce Pages
- Apex
- JavaScript
- Lightning Components
- Lightning Web Components
- System integration
- Web services