# Transform Process Builder to class Apex

Tags: apex, trigger

i have a Process Builder and i want to transform this class in process builder.
Who can help me ? i don't know how to start...
I actually learn salesforce and apex.

I have Object : Task he start process when a record is created or edited.
[image]

And the last action is Add Type in Activity Type RDV on Record Task
[image]

```
public static void PB17_EventAddTypeRDV (List <Event> e) {
 for (Event evt : e){
    if (evt.Type != null && evt.Type != evt.Type_RDV__c) {
        evt.Type_RDV__c = evt.Type;
    }
 }
 update e;
}
```

I have write this to translate process builder in code.
I think is good but i need a external opinion.

Comment: While we are sympathetic that you are new to Salesforce in general and Apex specifically, this is not a good question for SFSE. This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour). I would suggest you start here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/17126/81648.

Comment: Please do not post additional information or code that is for the question as a comment. Instead, edit your original question to add it. At the bottom left of every post you see "Share Edit Follow Flag". Click *Edit* under your question and add your code in the SFSE editor with three backticks (```) above and below it in order to format it as a code block.

Comment: I don't ever do anything with Tasks and Events, therefore am unfamiliar. If in the Process Builder the [Task] and the [Event] are in actuality the same record, then the code you have looks correct.

Comment: this is better done as a Before save Flow